# Python enumerating Network Devices

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, network-programming

In my project I need to achieve a list of all the **network devices** like WiFi , Bluetooth, Ethernet and many more ...
Is There a **Pythonic** way of getting that?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [netifaces](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netifaces).

```
>>> netifaces.interfaces()
['lo', 'eth0']
>>> netifaces.ifaddresses('eth0')
{17: [{'broadcast': 'ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff', 'addr': '00:25:11:ad:1b:dd'}], 2: [{'broadcast': '192.168.8.255', 'netmask': '255.255.255.0', 'addr': '192.168.8.135'}], 10: [{'netmask': 'ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::', 'addr': 'fe80::225:11ff:fead:1bdd%eth0'}]}
```

Comment: Thats a great way, But I could not manage to install this module. I tried everything but every time I got to another problem. Maybe there's a pre-compiles 'msi' file to install it on windows? On any other way it really seems impossible it me...Any Help?

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with Python on Windows. Unfortunately, it seems there is no pre-compiled version for Windows.

Comment: @FernandoRetimo There are now precompiled binaries for Windows.